OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `IUser` model once compiled
when I want to use findOne to get some values then it show me the error.
I am getting username from my url in my api to validate using zod

const UserModel =
  (mongoose.models.User as mongoose.Model<IUser>) ||
  mongoose.model<IUser>("IUser", UserSchema);

export default UserModel;

How i can fixed my issue?

Can you please add more details?

The code you provided seems to be an attempt to define a Mongoose model for the collection User, using TypeScript. It appears that you're trying to handle the case where the model may already exist, and if it does, you want to use the existing model instead of redefining it.
It seems to be the model has not created in the database. Please verify that before the calling the APIs.
You can try with the following snippets.
import { Schema, model, connect } from 'mongoose';

// define your schema here for the user model
const userSchema = {}

//  Create a Model.
const UserModel = model<IUser>('User', userSchema);

export default UserModel

Please refer for more information
